# ?ColorPrimary not working below android 5.0

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my app user can switch the theme between blue and green. everything is working fine in above android 5.0 version but below android 5.0 my application is **getting crashed**.

below is my **style** code

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Blue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bllueDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Green" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/bluish_green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bluish_green</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And my **drawable** file code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="?colorPrimary"></solid>
        <corners android:radius="3dp"></corners>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And my **layout** is

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable">
//other code
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: change this - <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></solid>

Comment: thanks for replying. @color/colorPrimary return color from color.xml class but i need theme's colorPrimary

Comment: You can use [`AppCompatResources.getDrawable(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/content/res/AppCompatResources.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int)) to inflate the drawable and set it programmatically as the background for the `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?attr/` references weren't supported within XML drawables in lower Android API levels. I'd assume it was level 21 when it was introduced, but I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Therefore you'd have to use color resources directly. If you need to have different colors for dynamic themes, you might be able to achieve something similar with correctly colored drawables provided by the theme.

Alternatively you could disregard these older Android versions in context of UI or even support.

Comment: You can use [`AppCompatResources.getDrawable(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/content/res/AppCompatResources.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int)) to inflate the drawable and set it programmatically as the background for the `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

In place of `?colorPrimary`, try and use this one `?attr/colorPrimary`

Comment: ?colorPrimary and ?attr/colorPrimary both is same. btw thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

Declare colorPrimary in your colors.xml and then try
`@color/colorPrimary` instead of `?colorPrimary`

Comment: @color/colorPrimary return color from color.xml class but i need theme's colorPrimary. but thanks for replying. let me know if you have

Comment: Well, you can make your theme colorPrimary like 
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

Comment: have you read my full question and respective code? because i have 2 theme and both theme have different colors.

Comment: It does not matter. The problem is that you are trying to use a color with a "?". You need to use "@color/yourColor". And for this you need to determine these colors in styles.xml. If there are two colors, make two colors in colors.xml. This is the standard way to implement such things.

Comment: I mean, you shouldn't try to get your theme colorPrimary. Instead you should declare  your colorPrimary in colors.xml so you can use it in drawables etc.

Comment: ?colorPrimary return theme color and @color/colorPrimary return me the color from colors.xml class. i need current theme color. i think you should go and check what is the diffrence between @color/colorPrimary and ?colorPrimary.

Comment: i want the drawable according to respective theme